# xml path returns "&lt;" for < and "&gt;" for > while executing query. how to get original value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, qsqlquery

I have a query which results some text on the basis of condition in it. 
but do not worry about all the conditions, I am only facing issue when 'md.OtherMedication = 'OTHERMEDICATION' and its comment to be shown.

So if comment have value like `<shubham>`
then it is returning

```
 &lt;shubham&gt;
```

which is not a expected result. following is the query i am using.

```
Select '' + CASE WHEN md.OtherMedication = 'OTHERMEDICATION' THEN md.Comment ELSE '' END
        FROM Medication md
        WHERE md.HraDiagnosisId = 94121 FOR XML PATH(N'')
```

I am expecting `<shubham>` as result.

Answer (score 13):

Try casting XML to Varchar with [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

```
select (Select '' + CASE WHEN md.OtherMedication = 'OTHERMEDICATION' 
                    THEN md.Comment ELSE '' END
        FROM Medication md
        WHERE md.HraDiagnosisId = 94121 FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)')
```

The above will remove all types of XML Tags and will give you plain text.

Answer (score 2):

`&lt;` and `&gt;` are `less than` and `greater than` tags of your xml.
you can replace them in your query so:

```
Select '' + CASE WHEN md.OtherMedication = 'OTHERMEDICATION' 
THEN Replace(Replace(md.Comment, '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>') ELSE '' END
FROM Medication md
WHERE md.HraDiagnosisId = 94121 FOR XML PATH(N'')
```